# Matlab fmincon: Updating variable even on zero gradient

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am using `fmincon` on a convex problem with four parameters and I supply my own gradients. The objective function is of the form

```
[likelihood, gradients] = somefunction(input_to_be_optimized, additonal_inputs)
```

The issue is, even with I manually set the fourth gradient to zero (inside the function, e.g., `gradients(4) = 0`), I see `fmincon` changing the fourth parameter on each iteration. How is this possible? As I understand, if the gradient is zero, the parameter should not change at all.

These are the options I use:

```
optimoptions('fmincon','Hessian', ...
    'bfgs','InitBarrierParam',1,...
    'ScaleProblem','obj-and-constr',...
    'GradObj','on','Algorithm','interior-point',...
    'SubproblemAlgorithm','ldl-factorization',...
    'Display', 'iter-detailed', 'Maxiter', 150, 'TolFun', 1e-8,...
    'ObjectiveLimit', -1e20,'MaxFunEvals',1000000,...
    'TolX',1e-8, 'OutputFcn', @outputFun);
```

Comment: What are your constraints? It might be moving that parameter to give the other parameters some room. Does it still do this if you use the active-set algorithm? With the interior point method, the constraints affect parameters even when you aren't on the boundaries.

Comment: @drhagen you are right, it doesn't do that when I use active set. But finally interior point moves the 4th variable very far from the start. Is this just a approximation error which gets snowballed?

Comment: Interior point algorithms add a penalty to the objective for getting close to violating a constraint. eg. `minimize f(x) subject to x < 2` will be transformed to something like the unconstrained problem  `minimize f(x) - log(x - 2)  / 1000`. This leads to @drhagen's point that, "with the interior point method, the constraints affect parameters even when you aren't on the boundaries." I bet something related to this is what's going on...

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Would any of you like to add that as an answer?